# Is there anyway to limit CPU frequency while device is in sleep?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

In the Linux kernel is it possible to (In Source Code) to limit to the max frequency of the CPU?

Comment: Does this answer your question? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349933/specify-cpu-frequency-as-a-kernel-cmd-line-parameter-of-linux-on-boot>

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the Linux kernel used by Android uses the standard Linux CPUFreq Governance

Take a look at the documentation to see whats supported and how you might setup your own. https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/a7827a2a60218b25f222b54f77ed38f57aebe08b/Documentation/cpu-freq